# how to delete <types>...</types> block

Tags: xml, bash, xml-namespaces

i have xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>sharinpix__SharinPix_Chatter__c-en_US</members>
        <members>sharinpix__SharinPix_Search_Affix__mdt-en_US</members>
        <members>sharinpix__VisitReport__c-en_US</members>
        <members>sharinpix__Visit__c-en_US</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

and i need to delete
this block  from this file
using  bash

```
<types>
        <members>sharinpix__SharinPix_Chatter__c-en_US</members>
        <members>sharinpix__SharinPix_Search_Affix__mdt-en_US</members>
        <members>sharinpix__VisitReport__c-en_US</members>
        <members>sharinpix__Visit__c-en_US</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
```

ChatGPT  solutions not working  at all
please advice

chatGPT
answers  but they  did not work

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: If I ask ChatGPT the following concretely formulated question, I get exactly the working answer with `xmlstarlet` that I would have given to your question. It also correctly takes into account your namespace: *How can I use xmlstarlet to remove the 'types' tag that contains the content 'CustomObjectTranslation' from the following XML file?*

Comment: @Cyrus: minus the namespace from OP question

Comment: @GillesQuénot: I used model GPT-4 (ChatGPT Plus).

Comment: Did you subscribed a paid version? Or where can I use ChatGPT4 for free @Cyrus? https://poe.com/GPT-4 is very limited use per days and regular https://chat.openai.com/ looks like GPT3*

Comment: @GillesQuénot: I subscribed at OpenAI to its ChatGPT Plus for 20 Dollar.

Comment: Per month I guess :/ Not sure I want to spend $20 each month for this. Will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Using `xmlstarlet`, with a default namespace `_`:

```
xmlstarlet edit -d '//_:types[./_:name="CustomObjectTranslation"]' file
```

Check [default namespace](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139523728)

##### With `xidel`:

```
xidel --xml -e 'x:replace-nodes(//types[./name="CustomObjectTranslation"],())' file
```

##### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexPage</name>
  </types>
  <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ApexTrigger</name>
  </types>
  <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```